# How to have multiple kafka consumer groups in application properties

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka and would like to have multiple consumer groupIds mentioned in the application yaml that I can use in my kafkaListener class where I am listening to multiple topics.

My kafka properties in application.yml file look like this for now

```
kafka:
    properties:
      topics:
        topic1: topic1
        topic2: topic2
    bootstrap-servers: server1,server2
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      retries: 4
    consumer:
      group-id: mygroupid
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Is there a way to have multiple groupIDs in the consumer block above.

Alternatively, I have give different groupIDs in kafkaListener in my spring code as follows, I am not sure how to set up the rest of the propeties like auto-offset-reset, key-deserializer etc:

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1",  groupId = "cd1")
  public void consumeMessage(String message) throws Exception {
    // some code goes here
  }
```

Please let me know how to accomplish what I am trying to do as I am new to kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot only autoconfigures one `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` and `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` from the yml, so all the properties are shared across all consumers. That's why we added the `groupId` (and use the `id` if `groupId` is not provided); this is the most common property that changes between consumers.

You can, of course, use property placeholders so `groupId = "${group.one}"` will use the property `group.one` from the yml.

To change more fundamental stuff like serializers/deserializers, if you are using a version earlier than 2.2.4, you will need to create multiple factories and container factories.

However, starting with version 2.2.4, you can now set any arbitrary kafka consumer property in the `KafkaListener` annotation...

```
/**
 * Kafka consumer properties; they will supersede any properties with the same name
 * defined in the consumer factory (if the consumer factory supports property overrides).
 * <h3>Supported Syntax</h3>
 * <p>The supported syntax for key-value pairs is the same as the
 * syntax defined for entries in a Java
 * {@linkplain java.util.Properties#load(java.io.Reader) properties file}:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code key=value}</li>
 * <li>{@code key:value}</li>
 * <li>{@code key value}</li>
 * </ul>
 * {@code group.id} and {@code client.id} are ignored.
 * @return the properties.
 * @since 2.2.4
 * @see org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
 * @see #groupId()
 * @see #clientIdPrefix()
 */
String[] properties() default {};
```

Note that these properties are in the native kafka dotted format (`auto.offset.reset`) not the boot hyphenated or camel case properties.

Here's an example from [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-properties):

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId="group", properties= {
    "max.poll.interval.ms:60000",
    ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG + "=100"
})
```

Again, the values can be property placeholders.

On the producer side, you need multiple factories still.